# Rendering does not work after login wait?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, rendering

I'm trying to render another component/pag with VUE 2 but I can't get it here my code:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2'
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
const options = {
  confirmButtonColor: '#FF0000',
  cancelButtonColor: '#ff7674',
};
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2, options);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/home',
    component: Home,
  }]
});
new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Button in login component:

```
methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("url del api", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
        });
        console.log(response.status)
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.$router.push('/home');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.$swal('Username or password incorrect!!!');
      }
```

The url changes once the login is correct to localhost:5273/home but does not render the home component but stays in the login.... what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot

I tried to redirect/render to a Home component with Vue router but I can't ...

Comment: what route is the user on when they're on the login view? the code snippet given only has a single `/home` route and `$router` can only navigate between different routes

Comment: I added the route where the login starts:
{
        path: '/login',
        component: Login
}

Comment: Have you correctly used the `<router-view>` component?